# ControllerAs with vm. syntax: how to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been reading in several places, including a few SO questions, that `ControllerAs` syntax is becoming the recommended pattern because, among other things, it is similar to how things will be done in Angular 2.

As a result I wanted to dig a little deeper in how the syntax wit `vm.` works.

Regardless of what you think about the approach, I would appreciate some pointers as to why this approach doesn't work,

```
//controllerAs with vm. syntax
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function () {

  var vm = this;
  vm.like = likeIt;
  vm.dislike = dislikeIt;
  vm.flag = flagIt;

    function likeIt() {
      alert('liked');
    },
    function dislikeIt() {
      alert('disliked');
    },
    function flagIt() {
     alert('flagged');
    }

});
```

**[Plunkr 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/EgHFP5gGsXcHBqUG32rd?p=preview)**

while this approach scope using `$scope`does

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

 $scope.like =  function () {
      alert('liked');
    };
  $scope.dislike =  function () {
      alert('disliked');
    };
  $scope.flag =  function () {
     alert('flagged');
    }

});
```

**[Plunkr 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/09dtm5IzapUlDPk3cBuN?p=preview)**

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

      <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
        <button ng-click="vm.like()">Like</button>
        <button ng-click="vm.dislike()">Dislike</button>
        <button ng-click="vm.flag()">Flag</button>

      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Hmm.. ;) I recognize this code from somewhere.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz it was the quickest way to have a quick and simple example, thanks!

Comment: I don't see `ControllerAs` here.

Comment: It's working just remove the comma(,) after function end.

Comment: Do you happen to know what vm actually stands for?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz `vm` as in `ViewModel` https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controlleras-with-vm

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar yeah sorted now, thanks.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes sorry, that wasn't the problem though.

Comment: @Ursus: it kinda was, judging by the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do this:

```
ng-controller="MyCtrl as action"
```

Then use it like so:

```
ng-click="action.like()"
```

Or angular won't recognize the functions.

Also found another issue, you have two `,` after the first two functions which breaks the code:

```
function likeIt() {
  alert('liked');
}, <-- Here
function dislikeIt() {
  alert('disliked');
}, <-- And here
function flagIt() {
 alert('flagged');
}
```

Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/R7oTvcUxjCqi8YXoLOoh?p=preview

Comment: You can refer to the parent `As` syntax within a child too.